# Kibana: Aggregation “Date Histogram” not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have one date field named: auditDate, having index type as date and format as Date.[explicitly pattern given: DD MMM YY]

I tried making date histogram using the same field but there is an issue with date shown in the histogram.

Example: I looked the data from discovery which shown in auditDate as 24 SEP 19 but when i used data histogram in table visualization that auditDate become 23 SEP 19.

Attached the snapshot for the same:
[image]

I am really surprise with the result. Can someone help on this.
I also posted the same question into elastic discussion page(https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-aggregation-date-histogram-not-working-properly/201829) untill now i did not get any response there, if i get any i will going to post the same here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a sample document whose date `24 SEP 19` becomes `23 SEP 19`? It might simply be a timezone issue.

Comment: For the sampling raw data from index looks as "auditDate": "2019-09-24" and when the same auditDate field used in Table visualization for aggregation of Data histogram with Daily interval as mentioned in the picture already, turn into the same back date issue. As I already mentioned I used the Date format in the index to become the format in wanted (which is 24 SEP 19).

Comment: Also, how I can identified that it is time zone issue? currently from kibana UI setting I used the UTC as default setting and at the time for ingestion we are using the UTC as timezone as well.

Comment: You can specify timeZone when you index document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-timezone

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem related to **timezone** calculation, check that in their [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) here in `time_zone` section.

So, i think you can fix it using something like:

```
"time_zone": "+01:00"
```